# Ajax returning PHP text rather than parsing the code

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, apache2.4

local environment is:
 Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) PHP/7.1.23 
all conf. files have been checked and re-checked and extra cmds added,e.g.:

```
        <IfModule>
       # PHP 7 specific configuration
       ....
       </IfModule>
```

```
        phpinfo() works fine etc.
```

the xmlhttp code is:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/getARCHIVE.php");
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','localhost');
          xmlhttp.send();

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
              console.log(this.responseText);
            } else {
             console.log("Loading...");
            };
          }
            }
```

and returns:
Loading...

```
    <?php
    echo 'hi everyone!';
    ?>
```

as text!

or ......

```
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'php/getArchive.php',
            crossDomain: true,
        error:      function( jqXHR, statusMessage, errorThrown){console.log('serverRequest for php:' + "\n" + statusMessage + "\n" + errorThrown);},
        success:    function( response, status, jqXHR ){
            callback(response);
        }
    });
    }
```

... returns the same text:

```
   serverRequest for php:
    parsererror
    Error: Invalid XML: <?php
    echo 'hi everyone!';
    ?>
```

accompanying comment/error is:
"XML Parsing Error: no root element found"

so how do I get the server to recognize the .php file - which is just:

```
     <?php echo 'hi everyone!'; ?>

i.e. the text that is being returned
```

Comment: reads like the php file in not actually being proccesed

Comment: any spaces before the opening php tag? ie `    <?php` rather than `<?php`?

Comment: Look at [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756240/xml-parsing-error-no-root-element-found-location) answers

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thankyou  very much- that was exactly the problem. I was entering file:///xxx into the browser rather than localhost:// - I assumed that the xmlhttp/ajax requests would be "served" via apache but evidently not.  Really appreciate your insight.